# Reset MegaCLI error count

Tags: dell-perc, megaraid, megacli

I have a system where `MegaCli64 -PdList -a0` shows media errors on one disk. After investigating the errors, I've decided not to take any action for now. I'd like to reset the error count, so that MegaCli will show 0 media errors unless there is another error. What arguments to MegaCLI do I need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to clear those errors besides replacing the disk and rebuilding the raid set with a healthy disk =/. I tried running MegaCli64 -h but could not find anything for clearing them